# How to get the user insert for a trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been trying to write a trigger that checks the amount of male students in a program does not exceed 60% but every time I implement it I get an invalid identifier for the `new.column_name`.

Here are the main tables that are involved with my trigger

```
CREATE TABLE Program 
(
    ProgID number,
    ProgName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FacID number NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ProgID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FacID) REFERENCES Faculty (FacID)
);

CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    StudID number,
    Fname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Lname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Gender varchar(50) NOT NULL Constraint  gen 
    CHECK(regexp_like(Gender, '^[M][a][l][e]$') OR
          regexp_like(Gender, '^[F][e][m][a][l][e]$')),
    Age int NOT NULL, 
    Nationality varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone_Number number (8) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    Sponser_Type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Fee_Percentage_Paid number DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (StudID)
);

CREATE TABLE Lecturer 
(
    LecID number, 
    Fname varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    Lname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Gender varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    Age int NOT NULL,
    Nationality varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone_Number number(8) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Email varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    FacID number NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (LecID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FacID) REFERENCES Faculty (FacID)
);
 
CREATE TABLE Class 
(
    ProgID number(10) NOT NULL,
    LecID number NOT NULL, 
    StudID number NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    Member_No number NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (ProgID) REFERENCES Program (ProgID),
    FOREIGN KEY (StudID) REFERENCES Student (StudID)
);
```

Here is the trigger I'm trying to implement.

```
delimiter $$
Create or REPLACE trigger gender_limit 
Before insert 
On Class 
For each row
Declare 
total_males NUMBER;
  Cursor counter IS select count (StudId) from (Select * from Class where ProgID = New.ProgID) a  
where StudID IN (Select StudID from Student where Gender = 'Male');  
BEGIN
OPEN counter;
FETCH counter INTO total_males;
    If (total_males = (40*0.6)) THEN    
    Begin
         Raise_application_error(-20003, 'Too many male students'); 
         Rollback;
    End;
    End if;
Close counter;
End$$
delimiter;
```

And here is the error it shows.

> Trigger GENDER_LIMIT compiled
>
> LINE/COL  ERROR
>
> 3/19      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> 3/82      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."PROGID": invalid identifier

Comment: New/old pseudorecords are prefixed with a colon in the trigger body: `:New.ProgID`

Comment: hi there thank you so much that seems to have fixed it

Comment: Why do you use `check(regexp_like(Gender,'^[M][a][l][e]$') or regexp_like(Gender, '^[F][e][m][a][l][e]$'))` and not `CHECK(gender IN ('Male', 'Female'))`?

Comment: oh its was a required statement for me to put in order to get marks on this assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger seems overly complicated and if many rows are inserted at the same time then it is going to trigger for every row and may, potentially, re-validate the same data multiple times. Additionally, as a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger you are not going to count the new students being added so if you have fewer than 60% males before the insert and add a large number of males then the trigger will not fire.

Your condition for raising an error is `total_males = (40*0.6)` which means that it will not fire if it is either less than or greater than that amount, which seems wrong.

Instead, you could use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger and check that there are no programs that match:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER gender_limit 
AFTER INSERT ON CLASS 
DECLARE
  has_too_many_males NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   has_too_many_males
  FROM   class c
         INNER JOIN student s
         ON (c.studid = s.studid)
  GROUP BY c.progid
  HAVING COUNT(CASE s.gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) >= 0.6
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

  Raise_application_error(-20003, 'Too many male students'); 
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    -- Nothing matching found.
    NULL;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wl_qO4x1)

If you only wanted to check the programs with inserted rows then you could convert the trigger into a compound trigger.

Comment: ok thank you so much for the help and explanation on what i did wrong and how to fix it